# Convert first 2 elements of tuple to integer

Tags: python

I have a csv file with the following structure:

```
1234,5678,"text1"
983453,2141235,"text2"
```

I need to convert each line to a tuple and create a list. Here is what I did

```
with open('myfile.csv') as f1:
    mytuples = [tuple(line.strip().split(',')) for line in f1.readlines()]
```

However, I want the first 2 columns to be integers, not strings. I was not able to figure out how to continue with this, except by reading the file line by line once again and parsing it. Can I add something to the code above so that I transform str to int as I convert the file to list of tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to cram all of the logic in a single line, just spread it out so that it is readable.

```
with open('myfile.csv') as f1:
    mytuples = []
    for line in f1:
        tokens = line.strip().split(',')
        mytuples.append( (int(tokens[0]), int(tokens[1]), tokens[2]) )
```

Real python programmers aren't afraid of using multiple lines.

Comment: You should probably use a try/except, real programmers are not afraid to ask for forgiveness either ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is a csv file. Treat it as such.

```
import csv

with open("test.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    result = [(int(a), int(b), c) for a,b,c in reader]
```

If there's a chance your input may not be what you think it is:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    result = []
    for line in reader:
        this_line = []
        for col in line:
            try:
                col = int(col)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            this_line.append(col)
        result.append(tuple(this_line))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `isdigit()` to check if all letters within element in row is digit so convert it to int , so replace the following :

```
tuple(line.strip().split(','))
```

with :

```
tuple(int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in (line.strip().split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* cram this all into one line if you really want, but god help me I don't know why you'd want to. Try giving yourself room to breathe:

```
def get_tuple(token_list):
    return (int(token_list[0]), int(token_list[1]), token_list[2])

mytuples = []
with open('myfile.csv') as f1:
    for line in f1.readlines():
        token_list = line.strip().split(',')
        mytuples.append(get_tuple(token_list))
```

Isn't that way easier to read? I like list comprehension as much as the next guy, but I also like knowing what a block of code does when I sit down three weeks later and start reading it!